# Making HTTPS Requests in Twisted

Tags: python, https, client, request, twisted

I am trying to write a client that can make both HTTP and HTTPS requests depending on how it is configured. For normal HTTP, I have been using twisted.web.client.Agent and using agent.request(METHOD, HOST, HEADERS, CONTENT) to make the requests. What I care about is that host field, when I do HTTP it works doing something like "http://localhost:8000", but if I switch to HTTPS, I get an error:

**Failure: twisted.web.error.SchemeNotSupported: Unsupported scheme: 'https'**

I am aware of the existence of the client.getPage method, but I was wondering if there was any similarly awesome and high level methods that I can make requests with just like agent.request, but using HTTPS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTPS support was only recently added to `twisted.web.client.Agent`.  If you can use Twisted 10.1, very recently released, then `Agent` will accept your HTTPS URLs.

Comment: You can see the progress of this feature as it was added here: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4023